# What is the alternative way of sending user location via sms on iOS6?

Tags: ios6, gps, sms, message

i have done a security app which locate a iPhone and send the GPS location of the phone through message to an associated number this functions works good until iOS 5, but the issue is sending SMS without users knowledge is restricted in iOS 6, so i need a help here instead of sending message, is there any other possible way or replacement for this function? any answer related to this method are appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified whether your ios app has a server. If yes, you can transmit location to server and that in turn can transmit it to intended user via specific api.

If this is not correct, [APNS](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html) is your friend. This is a way to send messages to desired devices only, the ones who explicitly registers through your app.

Another quite equivalent option is to store it in public back-end like [parse.com](http://parse.com). As soon as other devices start your app, they can pull your location from there. If their device is already live, parse.com can make sure to notify them as soon as you change your location value in their DB.

Comment: Sounds good thanks Nirav Bhatt, i will try with such possibilities.

Comment: If it helps glad to hear. Mark correct or upvote when you see fit as it will help you in getting future answers more quickly.